# How secure is ChaCha20?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, chacha

I want to implement a stream cipher to encrypt **very sensitive data** in my Python code. I heard about the ChaCha20 algorithm and the 
[PyCryptodome library](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/chacha20.html)
, but how secure is it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How secure is Salsa20?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/how-secure-is-salsa20)

Comment: @EllaRose Although I can see where you're coming from when comparing ChaCha20 with Salsa20, I can imagine that users of this site may not. A bit more info about [Salsa20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20) would be welcome. Besides that, it *does* use a new round function; it may not be directly obvious how much this would influence security.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It does say *possible* duplicate ;)

Comment: We cannot and should not comment here on the security of a library. You'd need to perform comprehensive research for that, possibly including a review of the given implementation (if those haven't been performed and well documented before). Answers here should focus on the algorithm alone and if the algorithm *can* be implemented securely.

Answer (score 8):

- Aumasson et al. Showed that ChaCha6  can be attacked with time complexity $2^{139}$ and ChaCha7 with $2^{248}$.
- Shi et al. gave an attack based on second-order differential with $2^{136}$ for ChaCha6 and $2^{246.5}$ for ChaCha7.
- Maitra, chosen IV cryptoanalysis and the time complexity of the attack showed that it can be reduced to $2^{239}$ for ChaCha7.
- Choudhuri and Maitra concluded ChaCha12 are
  sufficient for 256-bit keys against differential cryptanalysis using a hybrid model of non-linear round functions and linear approximation...

\begin{array} {|l|l|}
\hline
Attack & Evaluation \\
\hline
\text{Differential Analysis }      &                    \text{No attack found}\\
\text{Rotational Cryptanalysis}     &                   \text{No attack found}\\
\text{Boomerang Attack}        &                        \text{No attack found}  \\
\text{Linear Cryptanalysis}      &                      \text{No attack found}\\
\text{Distinguishing Attack}     &                      \text{No attack found}\\
\text{Guess and Determine Analysis}       &             \text{No attack found}\\
\text{Time-Memory-Data Tradeoff Attack }   &            \text{Protected}\\
\text{Practically ChaCha Algebraic Attack}   &          \text{No attack found} \\
\text{Attacks on Initialization Process}    &           \text{No attack found}\\
\text{Single Power Analysis }           &               \text{Protected}\\
\text{Practically Difference Power Analysis }    &      \text{Protected Practically}\\
\text{Cache Timing Attack}         &                    \text{No attack found}\\
\text{Fault Injection Analysis }   &                    \text{Protected Practically}\\
\hline
\end{array}

The above table and results come from [KDDI Research, Inc](http://www.cryptrec.go.jp/estimation/cryptrec-ex-2601-2016.pdf)

- simple power attack; though the rotation is vulnerable to power attack, they propose masking as a countermeasure.
- differential power analysis; they demonstrated that adversary can get all keys except $k_1$ which can be found in $2^{32}$, proposed masking as a countermeasure.
- Fault Injection Attack; they claim that the initial matrix $X$ or
  matrix $X^{(20)}$ will be output if injection is performed on the addition.

> A countermeasure against this sort of attacks is to separate variables; that is, distinct variables store the inputs and output of the addition. Consider an addition $z \leftarrow x+y$. The addition returns the initial value of variable z even if the addition is skipped. Thus, the adversary can get neither the value of variables $x$ and $y$. Algorithm 9 shows the implementation using countermeasure based on variable separation.
>
> We should note that variable separation in source-code level does not work

They include all attacks upto 2017 in their document. I couldn't find one in 2018.

Comment: How is the conclusion that ChaCha is practically resistant to fault injection reached? That one seems highly dependent on hypothesis made. At least in a setup where the same Chacha calculation is performed multiple times, it seems fault injection could work.

Comment: If you want, Ill we go deeper.

Answer (score -4):

ChaCha20 is a "primitive", in other words it's just one component of a secure cryptographic system (and PyCryptodome is a collection of primitives). So *in a way*, and from the perspective of a programmer, it's not secure at all. It's dangerous to use something so low-level.

In order to implement a secure crypto system, you need more than just encryption. Go with something like [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) or [PyNaCl](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/secret/) - they have already done all the work for you.

Comment: I've voted this down. On StackOverflow this could possibly count as an answer, as the question could suffer from the X-Y problem. But on crypto, when asked about the security of an algorithm, we want to focus on just that - not the protocol or system that the algorithm is used in.

Comment: Sure, I definitely answered the "real" question here. Maybe flag so that it can be converted into a comment. Or we change the question.