# Why we cannot brute force Elliptic Curve private key?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am learning ECC, I am confused a bit how it works for now. To my understanding, `G` is the starting point, k is how many times you apply the dot operation. And `Q` is the public key, which is the final point after you apply `k` times dot operations, like this

```
Q = kG
```

And then `Q` is the public key, and `k` is the private key. We assume it's really hard to find k given `Q` and `G` are known. The thing I don't understand (or I misunderstood) is, if the creator of this pair of key, can calculate `k` times of `G` to get `Q` easily in a reasonable amount of time, why can't attacker do the same? I can start from 1 dot operation, then 2 dot operations .... and eventually, I will hit a point that's the same as `Q`, and because the creator already did this in a reasonable amount of time, so I guess I can do it too (as they need to do `k` times of operation for thing like Diffie–Hellman)? And if `k` is super huge, doesn't it take the creator to take a super long time to generate and use it for key exchange? But I don't think it will be that easy, otherwise, it will be useless, just not sure which part I missed.

Comment: "`k` _is how many times you apply the dot operation_ ". ***NO!*** `k` is much too big to perform anything `k` times. Adding `G` to itself repeatedly, one less than `k` times, _would_ yield `Q`. But the holder of `k` uses shortcuts.

Comment: got it, I see, the part I missed is that there is a short cut, double and add method to quickly get to kG.

Comment: Or more simply https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58373/how-to-calculate-a-private-key-from-public-key-on-elliptic-curve and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61103/why-is-it-impossible-to-find-the-private-key-from-the-public-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creator of the key pair can do it efficiently because he has to calculate $kG$ for only *one* value of $k$. The cost would be something like $\log(k)$ elliptic curve operations. It's very small.

What you propose is to compute $1G$, $2G$, until you reach $kG$. Since $k$ is a big number (something like $2^{256}$, it is very big), then you have to do $2^{256}$ times more operations than the creator. It is very big.

Comment: thanks you so much, also thanks to @fgrieu, the missing part is that I didn't know there's a faster way to calculate kG. Since at very, I thought the dot operation is just something you can do one by one, but it turns out they are actually a field, where you can do double and add to get a crazy huge number easily.