# Understanding birthday attacks on 256 bit hashing and 512 bit hashing

Tags: hash, attack, birthday-attack

Does it make a difference against birthday attacks if the algorithm that I am using is 512 bit hashing?

Comment: Hey @fgrieu thank you for the edit. Can you please try to answer my question?

Comment: Hint: my [_Birthday problem for cryptographic hashing, 101_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39644/555) discusses the probability $p_n$ of a collision after hashing $n$ values among $k=2^b$ with an ideal $b$-bit is hash. This [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13305/555) concludes that $n\approx2^{92}$ is achievable, with a lots of money. Do the math and decide if $b=256$ or $b=512$ "makes a difference" for you.

Comment: Thank you, next time I will look up for similar questions before posting. I am new to the  community my  bad.

Comment: Probably, the first link answes my question, thanks guys.