# Is there any bias whatsoever in modern hash function outputs?

Tags: hash, randomness

The following is a representative example of a common hash function:-

[image: sha1]

The asymmetry is clear, and I would  expect additional edge effects  in the A and E output words. So I'd be surprised if the probability distributions between words A to E are identical to the nth degree. The same asymmetric construction argument clearly applies to all other hash architectures.

In general cryptography and as NIST does, it's common to treat a bias $\epsilon < 2^{-64}$ as negligible.  So an $\epsilon$ is expected of some degree as our constructions are imperfect.

The question therefore is: is there any estimate of the theoretical bias across the block width of hash function outputs? Assume the limiting case of an infinite number of hash inputs. Would the output probability distributions be (say for the above example) $P_{\infty}(A) = P_{\infty}(B) = P_{\infty}(C) = P_{\infty}(D) = P_{\infty}(E)$ exactly, and $\epsilon = 0.0$?

I won't be accepting the current answer as that deals with empirical measures, but I'm asking about theoretical expectations. There is no computationally bounded adversary.  I'm just curious.

---

NB. I take *"bias"* to mean the standard NIST definition (SP 800-90B) as *"A random process (or the output produced by such a process) is said to be biased with
respect to an assumed discrete set of potential outcomes (i.e., possible output values) if
some of those outcomes have a greater probability of occurring than do others."*

I'm really not sure if [Is any group of bits in a SHA-1 hash more/less unique than another?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20645/23115) is similar or not.

Comment: The most practical estimate, which only indirectly relates to your question, is if it's computationally feasible to distinguish a hash output from random. Modern strong hashes are computationally indistinguishable given reasonable limits (the adversary is capable of less than somewhere around 2^100 evaluations). However, they are almost certainly not perfectly unbiased. Presumably some simple hash functions still have some mathematical description of their bias, but even then the computational limit above will usually prevent you from detecting it.

Comment: And to add to the above, I doubt there's any reasonably complete mathematical description of the bias of a complex function like SHA256. Evaluating the exact bias can be harder than regular cryptoanalysis.

Comment: @Natanael Do you think that there might be an algebraic assessment somehow, given that empirical measures are infeasible?

Comment: @PaulUszak I'm not sure why the asymmetry matters. The diagram you are displaying is just one of 80 rounds. As you can see, each word "shifts" at the end of the round. Each round has every word affecting one word before they all shift, and this happens many times. Also, Whirlpool looks nothing like this. MD4, MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-2 look a bit like this (and a few slightly more obscure hashes like those of the RIPEMD family), but Whirlpool is based on AES and looks nothing like this. And SHA-3 (which uses the Keccak sponge function) also looks totally different. It's not even ARX.

Comment: @forest The image is a generic example of a hash function. Asymmetry matters as it is a discontinuity.  Discontinuities manifest themselves as anisotropy
 and variations in probability density function. We see this everywhere in science and engineering. The question is whether the bias $ \epsilon $ of the output words can really be 0.0.  Natanael and I believe there must be some quantitative bias. Are you aware of work done on this?

Comment: The definition of bias you gave is a binary property: either a distribution is uniform, in which case it is unbiased by this definition; or it is nonuniform, in which case it is biased.  Is there a _continuous measure_ of bias that you're asking about?  If not, it is almost certainly the case that for any ‘cryptographic hash function’ the output is technically ‘biased’ in this sense, but that almost-certainly-true property is of no practical consequence whatsoever—we have no idea in which way it might be biased.

Comment: @PaulUszak That is _not_ a generic hash function, it is SHA-1. That image represents MD4, MD5, SHA-1, SHA-2, and the RIPEMD family, but not all hash functions. That is not at _all_ how Whirlpool or SHA-3 look.

Comment: I would not mix TRNG and Hashes. NIST uses DRBG with Hashes to explicitely remove bias from biased random sources.

Answer (score 3):

If there were any detectable bias, I wouldn't be posting about it on a forum of pseudonymous wackos like me on the internet—I would be getting top billing (or beaking, as the case may be) in a top-tier cryptography conference, and the champagne would be popping, and Twitter would be abuzz with speculation, and Hacker News would be *extra* insufferable.

Specifically, with the exception of 2-pass Snefru[[1]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-46766-1_11)[[2]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-71039-4_28), **no major hash function with advertised preimage and collision resistance has *ever* seen its preimage resistance broken**[[3]](https://z.cash/technology/history-of-hash-function-attacks/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://z.cash/technology/history-of-hash-function-attacks/)).  (Yes, there's a paper that everyone and their dog cites on an MD5 preimage attack[[4]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01001-9_8), but it's not *cheaper* than the best generic attack[[5]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50429).)

---

<sub>P.S.  The formula $\epsilon = 2^{-(s n - k)/2}$ appears to be a quotation from an ID Quantique marketing whitepaper with a garbled definition which Paul read out of context to draw a nonsense conclusion in the [self-accepted answer of his own that he cited](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/61744).</sub>

Comment: @fgrieu Thomsen: ‘The total complexity of the attack is about $2^{73}$ compression function evaluations.  Memory requirements are about $2^{73}$ message blocks.’ (p. 8)  Muller: ‘[I]t will cost about $2^{104}$ applications of the compression function.  In addition, a memory of $2^{71}$ is required.  This is much faster than a naive exhaustive search.’ (p. 14)  These are not _cheaper_ than generic search.

Comment: There is a report of a preimage attack of cost $2^{73}$ evaluations on MD2: Søren S. Thomsen's [_An improved preimage attack on MD2_](https://ia.cr/2008/089) (2008). It improves Lars R. Knudsen and John E. Mathiassen's _Preimage and Collision Attacks on MD2_ (in [proceedings of FSE 2005](https://doi.org/10.1007/11502760_17)) with a claimed $2^{97}$, improving on Frédéric Muller's [_The MD2 Hash Function is Not One-Way_](https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/archive/fr/sciences/fichiers/lcr/mu04c.pdf) with $2^{104}$ [fixed]. Indeed memory cost is high.

Comment: Hey, the $\epsilon$ formula is a standard NIST formula widely accepted by all TRNG architects.  I'm sorry that you can't understand it, but the implication of your self labelled 'wacko' answer is that $\epsilon = 0.0$ which is unlikely isn't it?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage, nice answer, including the ones in the links I followed from here. What is *beaking* at a crypto conference? I get the image of a verbose bird shaking its head.

Comment: @kodlu well I'm not a duck or a platypus…

Comment: Why do you say that the equation is out of context? And why is it nonsense? The context is perfect and the conclusions validated by NIST and many other works. Your answer to that linked question is poor, hence I was forced to look elsewhere. Ridiculing people's question's isn't cool.

Comment: @PaulUszak No one's questions are being ridiculed. Squeamish Ossifrage is pointing out only that you took the equation from a marketing whitepaper out of context and, as a result, drew a nonsense conclusion.