# Is truncated hash collision resistant if original hash is collision resistant?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Let's say I have a collision resistant hash function $H: \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ and I want to create another collision resistant hash function $H': \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ using $H$ that leaks a bit of input. Would this still constitute a collision resistant hash function?

$$H'(x\mathbin\Vert b) = H(x)_{[1\ldots n-1]} \mathbin\| b$$

(Here, $b$ is a single bit)

Comment: Welcome to Cryptgraphy.se. What is the origin of this question? What does $[1..n-1]$ means here?

Comment: It means the first n-1 bits, or everything but the $n$th bit.

Comment: There's no general answer. If n is just on the border of being collision resistant, then truncating 1 bit could make finding a collision feasible. If n is well above that bound, then truncating 1 bit wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Hint: assume $G: \{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n-1}$ is a random oracle/function (or perhaps, is to $n$ what SHA3-512 is to 513), thus collision-resistant. Make $H$ a small variation of $G$ that's still collision resistant, but with $H'$ that trivially collides.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus is answering a different question from fgrieu - you are addressing "if $H$ is a random collision resistant hash function, is $H'$ likely to be as well; fgrieu is hinting towards answering the question "if $H$ is an arbitrary CR hash function, is $H'$ guaranteed to be one as well"

Comment: While not a direct duplicate, I think [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3155/975) answers your question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116008/discussion-on-question-by-doctopus-is-truncated-hash-collision-resistant-if-orig).